# Read input text files into Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, file

I have 2 large text files, the 1st with a lot of Years and the 2nd has the Months for each Year. I want to put both text files into arrays so I can sort them.

The text files looks like for e.g.:

1st file = Years

2015

2015

2015

---

2nd file = Months

January

February

March

---

I want the result to look like this:

```
int[] Year = {"1st File??"};
string[] Months = {"2nd File??"};
```

Comment: You forgot to show us what you have already tried

Comment: I have been parsing text files for over 40 years.  Without seeing more of the data it is not possible to really answer your questions. Since you said that the files are large it looks like you only put out a summary of the files without all the text.  Text files are very not easy to parse since they are very sensitive to spacing and where line returns are located.

Answer (score 1):

Since the months are strings, the second array is trivial to generate using [`File.ReadAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which takes a path, reads each line into a separate string, and returns the result as an array:

```
string[] months = File.ReadAllLines("File2.txt");
```

For the years, you can use the same method to get a string array, then use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) to apply `int.Parse` to each string:

```
IEnumerable<int> years = File.ReadAllLines("File1.txt").Select(l => int.Parse(l));
```

Note that `Select` returns an `IEnumerable<int>` rather than an `int[]`, but unless you need to use indexing operations, it probably isn't necessary to convert to an array. If you do need to, you can apply the `ToArray` method to `years`.